# How to compile or convert sass / scss to css with node-sass (no Ruby)?

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, node-sass, libsass

I was struggling with setting up libsass as it wasn't as straight-forward as the Ruby based transpiler. Could someone explain how to:

1. install libsass?
2. use it from command line?
3. use it with task runners like gulp and grunt?

I have little experience with package managers and even less so with task runners.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

I picked node-sass implementer for libsass because it is based on node.js.

### Installing node-sass

- (Prerequisite) If you don't have npm, install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) first.
- `$ npm install -g node-sass` installs node-sass globally `-g`.

This will hopefully install all you need, if not read libsass at the bottom.

### How to use node-sass from Command line and npm scripts

General format:

```
$ node-sass [options] <input.scss> [output.css]
$ cat <input.scss> | node-sass > output.css
```

Examples:

1. `$ node-sass my-styles.scss my-styles.css` compiles a single file manually.
2. `$ node-sass my-sass-folder/ -o my-css-folder/` compiles all the files in a folder manually.
3. `$ node-sass -w sass/ -o css/` compiles all the files in a folder automatically whenever the source file(s) are modified. `-w` adds a watch for changes to the file(s).

More usefull options like 'compression' [@ here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface). Command line is good for a quick solution, however, you can use task runners like Grunt.js or Gulp.js to automate the build process.

You can also add the above examples to npm scripts. To properly use npm scripts as an **alternative to gulp** read [this comprehensive article @ css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/) especially read about [grouping tasks](https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/#article-header-id-11).

- If there is no `package.json` file in your project directory running `$ npm init` will create one. Use it with `-y` to skip the questions.
- Add `"sass": "node-sass -w sass/ -o css/"` to `scripts` in `package.json` file. It should look something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test" : "bla bla bla",
    "sass": "node-sass -w sass/ -o css/"
 }
```

- `$ npm run sass` will compile your files.

### How to use with gulp

- `$ npm install -g gulp` installs Gulp globally.
- If there is no `package.json` file in your project directory running `$ npm init` will create one. Use it with `-y` to skip the questions.
- `$ npm install --save-dev gulp` installs Gulp locally. `--save-dev` adds `gulp` to `devDependencies` in `package.json`.
- `$ npm install gulp-sass --save-dev` installs gulp-sass locally.
- Setup gulp for your project by creating a `gulpfile.js` file in your project root folder with this content:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

**A basic example to transpile**

Add this code to your gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

`$ gulp sass` runs the above task which compiles .scss file(s) in the `sass` folder and generates .css file(s) in the `css` folder.

To make life easier, let's add a watch so we don't have to compile it manually. Add this code to your `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

All is set now! Just run the watch task:

```
$ gulp sass:watch
```

### How to use with Node.js

As the name of node-sass implies, you can write your own node.js scripts for transpiling. If you are curious, check out node-sass project page.

### What about libsass?

Libsass is a library that needs to be built by an implementer such as sassC or in our case node-sass. Node-sass contains a built version of libsass which it uses by default. If the build file doesn't work on your machine, it tries to build libsass for your machine. This process requires Python 2.7.x (3.x doesn't work as of today). In addition:

> LibSass requires GCC 4.6+ or Clang/LLVM. If your OS is older, this version may not compile. On Windows, you need MinGW with GCC 4.6+ or VS 2013 Update 4+. It is also possible to build LibSass with Clang/LLVM on Windows.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev node-sass` compile scss files too ?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes it does :)

Comment: You can add `"sass": "node-sass -w sass/ -o css/"` to your scripts. There is more to it than just this, I will write a new Q&A about it if I ever had time.

Comment: @Thoran: I did but on npm start the scss is not getting compiled to css as it should be. Here is the code:
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run sass\" ",
    "sass": "node-sass -w app/sass/ -o app/css/",

Comment: @Thoran is it possible to run another script after node-sass builds source files from watching? Like what if one wanted to run postcss + autoprefixer after building

Comment: You can do is with npm scripts. Follow the given link. You can also do it with gulp; I recommend gulp for large projects.

Comment: Why did you install gulp both globally and locally? Is it so you could use gulp on the command line but also have it included as a dependency in your project. If that is the case then would you also want to do that with node-sass as well instead of just installing it globally?

Comment: @PublicHandle Perhaps that was the reason, I don't remember. `node-sass` is in [`gulp-sass`'s dependencies](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/master/package.json#L26), so no need to install it locally.

Comment: @PublicHandle global install of gulp is necessary if you want to run gulp tasks from command line.

Comment: @Thoran Ah that makes sense then if node-sass is a dependency of gulp-sass so it's not needed locally while gulp itself is needed in both places so it can be run on the command line and be included as a dependency in the project. Thanks again, awesome write-up!

Comment: How would I call `sass.render()` when I want to compile all `.scss` files in that directory and write a `.css` file for every output? I don't want to invoke command line like `node-sass -w sass/ -o css/` but call the render method myself.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I never used it that way. Which task runner are you using?

Comment: @Thoran I was trying to find out if I can avoid using a task runner like gulp or grunt and write a simple npm script that does what I need. I looked into node-sass, the command line obviously uses glob and loops over the files. I guess it's best to simply copy that code.

Comment: So in order to avoid using _Ruby_, one can use _node.js_, a specific version of _Python_ AND a _C++_ library one needs to compile if usin Windows? That simplifies things a lot.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I think for most people `npm install -g node-sass` works including those using windows.

Comment: After getting 'An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory' errors when giving the command prompt I noticed I had to manually create the *example.css* in the given folder or use the *my-css-folder/* output line to automatically create *main.css* in the given folder.
Your answer gave me hint to my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good summary. Very comprehensible, I don't even know what they wrote on their npm page.

Answer (score 7):

`npx node-sass input.scss out.css`

Answer (score 6):

The installation of these tools may vary on different OS.

Under Windows, node-sass currently supports VS2015 by default, if you only have VS2013 in your box and meet any error while running the command, you can define the version of VS by adding: --msvs_version=2013. This is noted on the [node-sass npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

So, the safe command line that works on Windows with VS2013 is:
npm install --msvs_version=2013 gulp node-sass gulp-sass

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 using *node v6.11.2* and *npm v3.10.10*, in order to execute directly in any folder:

```
> node-sass [options] <input.scss> [output.css]
```

I only followed the instructions in [node-sass Github](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install):

1. Add [node-gyp prerequisites](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) by running as Admin in a Powershell (it takes a while):

   ```
   > npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
   ```
2. In a **normal command-line** shell (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+cmd+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) run:

   ```
   > npm install -g node-gyp
   > npm install -g node-sass
   ```

   The `-g` places these packages under `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`. You may check that `npm\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass` now exists.
3. Check if your **local account (not the System)** `PATH` environment variable contains:

   ```
   %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm
   ```

   If this path is not present, *npm* and *node* may still run, but the modules *bin* files will not!

**Close the previous shell** and reopen a new one and run either `> node-gyp` or `> node-sass`.

Note:

- The `windows-build-tools` **may not be necessary** (if no compiling is done? I'd like to read if someone made it without installing these tools), but it did add to the admin account the `GYP_MSVS_VERSION` environment variable with `2015` as a value.
- I am also able to run directly other modules with *bin* files, such as `> uglifyjs main.js main.min.js` and `> mocha`