# How to compile scss to css with node-sass

Tags: css, node.js, sass, npm, node-sass

I have a master.scss with many imports from other .scss files. If I change a * .scss file master.css is generated automatically.

I use only the NPM, no Gulp or Grunt! This should remain so.

My current build script:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch-sass": "sass --watch src/scss/master.scss:dist/css/master.css"
}
```

That's nice but takes a long time to compile!

Now I'm trying to use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass). It should compile very fast.
Unfortunately, I do not understand it completely ...
**node-sass** is installed, via `npm install node-sass`

Where do I use the following (from docs)?

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
sass.render({
  file: scss_filename,
  [, options..]
}, function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
// OR
var result = sass.renderSync({
  data: scss_content
  [, options..]
});
```

This is not so in the `package.json`, right?

Here's a tutorial, what I've read:  [Using NPM as a Task Runner](http://paulcpederson.com/articles/npm-run/)

The script is good. How can I use it?

```
"scripts": {
  "sass": "node-sass sass/ -o build/css/"
}
```

*This will compile all of the sass files (that don't start with an underscore) to the build/css/ directory.*

I hope for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this covers your question:
[How to compile or convert sass / scss to css with node-sass (no Ruby)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-can-i-transpile-compile-sass-or-scss-with-node-sass-and-gulp-sass-based-on)

If it's an option for you I would recommend using grunt, it will make things a lot simpler and faster. This grunt plugin is probably the best option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass

// UPDATE

I followed the tutorial you sent and it's very straightforward.
You create a file in your root folder called "package.json" containing the following:

```
{
  "watches": {
    "sass": "sass/**"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass sass/ -o build/css/",
    "dev": "rerun-script"
  }
}
```

You then open the command line in the root folder and run the following:

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

The above installs node-sass

You then run:

```
npm install --save-dev rerun-script
```

The above creates a watch task so you don't have to rerun node-sass everytime you make changes

And last you run

```
npm run dev
```

Done!

Comment: I would like to try it first without gulp / grunt.
Finally, it goes also without, see Tutorial link.
I just do not know how I use "node-sass" properly.

Comment: Before downvoting my answer you could have a look at the first link that I sent. The answer you are looking for is there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31448585/4265499

Comment: Sorry, misclick ... No, the answer is not there.
The aim is to compile the run as a task.

Comment: How about using the command line directly and doing sthing like:$ node-sass src/scss/ -o dist/css/

Comment: I do not want to start the command line with each change!
That must go automatically!

Comment: I updated my initial answer. It works fine for me. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @user3852555 Were you able to find the solution to compile scss to css on the go after doing npm start without starting command line on each change. Please share.

Answer (score 5):

[Documentation.](https://gist.github.com/artamonovdev/5f24aaca504e4d1b299bba0413f0a57d)

If you want automatically compile files then you need to put the flag -w

```
node-sass -w -r assets/src/scss/ -o assets/dist/css/
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build:js": "watchify assets/src/js/main_1.js -o 'exorcist assets/dist/js/main_1.js.map > assets/dist/js/main_1.js' -d -t [babelify --presets [latest]]",
    "build:scss": "node-sass -w -r assets/src/scss/ -o assets/dist/css/",
    "build": "npm run build:scss & npm run build:js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "exorcist": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  }
}
```

Actual version of package.json: https://gist.github.com/artamonovdev/5f24aaca504e4d1b299bba0413f0a57d

Comment: Your answer by far is the least "krufty" method of getting custom scss set up and running for a project that has BS4 and brand overrides required. All my other research resulted in front-end dev hostile complex configs.

Answer (score 5):

The `watch` mode in `node-sass` doesn't run the first compilation. It supposes that you have already ran `node-sass`.

Personally, I use something like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -o /path/to/dist /path/to/src",
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass && npm run sass -- --watch --recursive"
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this: `npm run sass:watch`

Comment: Then I add this "npm run sass:watch" to my "start" script so this can happen automatically using `npm start`?

Comment: @SpaceNinja yes