# How to compile scss to css on npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass, gulp

I am unable to compile scss files to css once the application is run using npm start. Is there a way to live reload a sass to css like ts are compiled to js by utility tsc:w.So I have to stop the build and then do gulp watch or node-sass command to compile scss to css and then build solution again using npm start. I tried below approaches but none worked. 
Here is the code in package.json:

Using gulp watch:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"gulp\" ", 
//also tried gulp watch and that did not work too.
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"gulp watch\" ",
```

here is my gulppfile.js in the root directory:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Using node-sass command:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run sass\" ",             
"sass": "node-sass -w app/sass/ -o app/css/",
```

Could anyone pls tell what I am missing or what is the right way to do it? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `gulp` will run the default task which you haven't included in your gulpfile. You need to add this

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass','watch']);
```

Comment: ok will try it. but i have gulp watch in gulpfile.js as well as in package.json start script. It should have run, isnt it?

Comment: if you run `gulp watch` by it self, it would only run the watch task without compiling. Therefore you need to add both into a default task.

Answer (score 8):

The solution to this issue has been explained in other threads, see: [How to compile scss to css with node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896279/how-to-compile-scss-to-css-with-node-sass)

However, here's my solution using the run-watch program, nodemon:

```
npm install node-sass nodemon --save-dev
```

In package.json, add these to your "scripts":

```
 "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss src/input.scss src/styles.css",
 "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\" "
```

Then, in your "start" script, use this:

```
 "start": "concurrently \"node app.js\" \"npm run watch-css\" "
```

Next, we need to install the concurrently package:

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

To compile and serve your files,

```
npm start
```

Therefore, the "npm start" command triggers a build that starts the app and concurrently calls the "run watch-css" command which in turn calls "build-css" to compile scss to css in real-time through nodemon. It compiles and refreshes live when you edit any scss in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Without gulp

```
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\"  \"npm run build-css\"",
  "build-css": "node-sass resources/css/sass/style.scss resources/css/style.css",
```

Comment: Thanks @Mircea - will surely try this out!!