# Error when running Ionic serve in Ionic 2

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, gulp, node-sass

When I ran ionic serve in node.js command line or GitHub power shell, I encounter this error.

```
There is an error in your gulpfile:
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:188:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡]>
```

Noted I could miss out node sass and gulp, and some windows user need visual studio, I follow this link [How to compile or convert sass / scss to css with node-sass (no Ruby)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-to-transpile-compile-sass-scss-with-node-sass-and-gulp-sass-based-on-libsas)
Using this command `npm install --msvs_version=2013 gulp node-sass gulp-sass`

Now, I encounter this error.

```
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  ionic serve
Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'vinyl'

Do you need to run `npm install`?
```

all the version i sued are as below:

```
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  npm -v
3.9.0
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  node -v
v5.11.1
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  gulp -v
[17:09:03] CLI version 3.9.1
[17:09:03] Local version 3.9.0
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  node-sass -v
node-sass       3.7.0   (Wrapper)       [JavaScript]
libsass         3.3.6   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  cordova -v
6.1.1
D:\GitHub\stockMarketApp [master ≡ +245 ~0 -5054 !]>  ionic -v
2.0.0-beta.25
```

Comment: Try to `npm install vinyl`

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the latest `gulp-sass` version in `package.json`; It's a dependency of node-sass + required by Ionic, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"
  },
```

---

Uninstall gulp-sass

```
$ npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass
```

---

Reinstall gulp-sass

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2
```

---

There are a large number of issues pertaining to node-sass installation.
You may have to rebuild node-sass: `$ npm rebuild node-sass`

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me:

```
Uninstall gulp-sass                
 $ npm uninstall --save-dev gulp-sass
Reinstall gulp-sass
 $ npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2

 $ npm install bower
 $ionic serve --lab
```