# How can I compile Sass in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-mac

So I would like to use my Macbook to build a new app but the tools I typically use for SASS, mainly the Web Compiler extension, are not supported on Mac.  Is there a similar tool I can use on Mac in VS to compile Sass?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, Community Edition.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I will let you know as soon as i figure it out

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. Did you guys figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Web Compiler extension it seems to use [node-sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-to-compile-or-convert-sass-scss-to-css-with-node-sass-no-ruby) to compile the .sass files.

If you can get that working on the command line then you could do one of the following:

1. Run that command from the Terminal window.
2. Add a post or pre-build step to the project which runs that command.
3. Look at installing the BuildWebCompiler NuGet package which looks to be used by the Web Compiler extension to enable files to be generated on build.
4. Install the [Task Runner Explorer extension](https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2019/01/04/TaskRunnerExplorerInVisualStudioMac/) and setup a package.json with a command that will run node-sass. Then the NPM task runner should be able to detect that and run it.

Comment: WebCompiler can't work in MacOS.