# Does Sass automatically generate a css-style.css file and place in the Sass folder?

Tags: css, node-sass

I have a website project with the main folder on my desktop with a Css folder inside is the style.css

and have installed Sass in Visual Studio Code
Have Windows 10 operating system with node sass for windows running with npm

Sass file structure architecture has one file for each part of the website with a _base.scss file for color variable and font variables etc.
And a main.scss file for the @imports

my index style sheet

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

within the Main Sass folder in my VSC project I now see a css-style.css sitting there with the other individual .scss files. Is this correct?

json file

```
 "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
"devserver": "live-server --browser=firefox",
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
"compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css output-style compressed",
"build": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
```

index file is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: what's in it? it might the output from your main scss file

Comment: yes all the information is there including the _scss files that  are not being rendered in live server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a path for your style.css.
Basically you can do this:

```
sass your/path/to/style.scss your/path/to/style.css
```

If you execute the sass command in your sass folder, it will create a ".css" in this folder.

Maybe you find help in this guide -> https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: since i'm new what do you recommend be best way

Comment: in your case you need to use "node-sass" in your command line. There is also a nice description with node-sass -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-to-compile-or-convert-sass-scss-to-css-with-node-sass-no-ruby

Comment: ok thanks will check it out i also showed the json file settings and css linking from index if you get chance to see

Comment: I can't help you with your config, but i can help you to do this from command line. If your sass and css folder are in your root project directory you can try this command: "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css". This should compile all imports from main.scss to your style.css

Comment: Looks like problem is  solved as I deleted the css-style.css file! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

no its not generate automatically unless you set in with tools like gulp or adjust it with your IDE tools also you can use third-party software like http://koala-app.com/ on windows for generate css file automatically

Comment: what do you recommend I do with it now delete the file? Looks like it has imput from the main scss file