# How to include scss compilation to css during CRA build

Tags: reactjs, sass, build, babeljs, node-sass

I want to create npm package from my CRA app. Lets say I have some components where I include .scss file. When I build this app, I compile .tsx/ts components to JavaScript files with their definitions.

Compiled folder hierarchy structure may looks like this

```
components
=> BurgerMenu
    => BurgerMenu.d.ts
    => BurgerMenu.js
    => BurgerMenu.js.map
```

However compiled JavaScript files imports scss files `require("./burgerMenu.scss");` instead of css file and css file is not compiled into specific folder.

Desired result is below

```
components
=> BurgerMenu
    => BurgerMenu.d.ts
    => BurgerMenu.js
    => BurgerMenu.js.map
    => BurgerMenu.css
```

How I can set sass compile during build and in every single component change import from scss to css?

Sample BurgerMenu component

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./burgerMenu.scss";

export const BurgerMenu = (props) => {
  //removed for brevity
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/js/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/js/index.d.ts",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "tag": "prerelease"
    },
  },
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:lib": "yarn build:babel && yarn build:types && node ./scripts/copyTS.js",
    //TODO: node sass compile
    "build:babel": "concurrently \"yarn build:babel:esm && yarn build:babel:umd\" \"yarn build:babel:cjs\"",
    "build:babel:cjs": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=cjs babel --source-maps --extensions \".js,.ts,.tsx\" src --out-dir dist/js --presets=@babel/env",
    "build:babel:esm": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=esm babel --source-maps --extensions \".js,.ts,.tsx\" src --out-dir dist/esm",
    "build:babel:umd": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=umd babel --source-maps --extensions \".js\" dist/esm --out-dir dist/umd --plugins=transform-es2015-modules-umd",
    "build:types": "tsc -p tsconfig.gen-dts.json",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "develop": "yarn build:types && yarn build:babel:esm --skip-initial-build --watch --verbose",
    },  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-sass` npm package can be used to convert all the .scss files to .css files and the same can be used your modules for importing

Add this in your package.json

```
"scripts" : {
    ...
    "build-css": "node-sass src/scss/ -o dist"
}
```

Here is a nice explanation of how `node-sass` can be used - [How to compile or convert sass / scss to css with node-sass (no Ruby)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-to-compile-or-convert-sass-scss-to-css-with-node-sass-no-ruby)